# C# DataGridView how to programatically fire the selected event

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a form and I have the following code:

```
 //Scroll to the last row
            gridStore.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridStore.RowCount - 1;
            // select new row
            gridStore.Rows[gridStore.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

I realize that .Selected doenst fire the SelectionChange event:

```
 private void gridStore_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

And I need to fire that event when the row is selected programatically.

> Any clue?

Comment: Try settings dgv.CurrentCell or calling the gridStore_SelectionChanged event manually after your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly figured out, when the `SelectMode` set to `FullRowSelect` `SelectionChanged` event will not fire.

You have two workarounds to fix this issue.

**Option 1**

Separate the logic you would like to perform in common between `gridStore_SelectionChanged` and when you update the selection explicitly and call that method in both events.

```
private void DoSomething()
{

}

private void gridStore_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
     DoSomething();
}
```

and

```
gridStore.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridStore.RowCount - 1;
// select new row
gridStore.Rows[gridStore.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;

DoSomething();
```

**Option 2:**

Explicitly you trigger the event after making the selection (not preferable way, but works).

```
gridStore.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridStore.RowCount - 1;
// select new row
gridStore.Rows[gridStore.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
gridStore_SelectionChanged(this, new EventArgs())
```